# Tkinter (Mac, Python 2.6): Image not visible with create_image and Menu item

Tags: image, canvas, menu, tkinter, invisible

I've defined a menu which should show an image (JPG, 250x250) in an item.

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def show_photo():
  img=Image.open("image.jpg")  
  photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)   
  width=photo.width();
  height=photo.height()   
  w=Tkinter.Toplevel(root)  
  w.geometry(str(width+2)+'x'+str(height+2))
  w.title(str(width)+'x'+str(height))  
  canvas=Tkinter.Canvas(w, bg="black", width=width, height=height)  
  canvas.pack()  
  img=canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=Tkinter.NW,image=photo)
  xxx    # NameError

root=Tkinter.Tk() 
mainmenu = Tkinter.Menu(root) 
menu1 = Tkinter.Menu(mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu1)
menu1.add_command(label="Show photo", command=show_photo)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
root.mainloop()
```

Unless I put a wrong line (here: xxx), the image doesn't appear, only a correct size black rectangle.

Any clue ?

Thanks by advance,
Eric.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this: your image is in a local variable. When `show_photo()` exits, the image reference gets garbage-collected and thus the image gets destroyed. When that happens Tkinter is no longer able to show the image because the data is gone.

Try saving a reference to the image, either in a global or instance variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! Here, "global photo" is necessary just before defining "photo".